# SvelteKit client hooks?

Tags: sveltekit

I am following [this post](https://medium.com/@varu87/azure-ad-authentication-in-sveltekit-f596cfa8a349) on authenticating against Azure AD using SvelteKit and it's working great, except I can't figure out how to use the client hooks.  The post doesn't, but looking at

I tried this in `/src/hooks.client.ts` and it didn't work, then noticed that page said it was a universal hook and added it to `/src/hooks.ts`.

```
export function reroute({ url }) {
    console.log('reroute():', url)
    return '/hello'
}
console.log('RUNNING: hooks.client.ts')
```

Neither seems to be called, my app never reroutes to `/hello` and I don't see the console.log in either the browser or in my console running the dev server.   Am I using it wrong?  Looking at the [sveltekit source](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/main/packages/kit/src/runtime/client/client.js) it's usage seems very simple.

The 'RUNNING' console does log once in the browser when I first load a page so the module is getting read.   I don't see the one in hooks.ts though, so it seems that file isn't even looked at.

Why my client hooks aren't running is my main question, but maybe I should look at using the layout page instead of a hook for protecting routes?

Comment: Reroute is for translating localized URLs. For protecting routes you should use the `handle` hook.

Comment: @brunnerh I thought that was server-only

Comment: So? It runs on every request.